# How to define a skewed Gaussian distribution using mode and two points?

Tags: python, algorithms, distributions, normal-distribution

I want to define a Gaussian distribution function and plot it in python using the mode and two points parameter values instead of using the mean and standard deviation.

For example, I have `mode=110` and `two points : (40, 160)` for asymmetrical points.

Or `mode=100` and `two points = (50,150)` for symmetrical points.

I tried with this code below, but I don't how I can add the second point to the formula which is returned by the function? Since I have two points, and I don't know how to define a function that depends on two points and mode.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
def gaussian(x, mode, inf_point):
    return 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*inf_point)*np.exp(-np.power((x - mode)/inf_point, 2)/2)
x = np.linspace(0,256)
plt.plot(x, gaussian(x, mode, inf_point))
```